# How to send both video and canvas streams to the remote client connected using RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, webrtc

We are trying to create small video chat application where remote user can see our local video and the drawings we are doing on the local video. To connect to the remote user, we are using RTCPeerConnection.

We are using a video element and a canvas on top of video to draw an arrow or some other two dimensional objects and we are passing the video and canvas as streams and receiving on the remote client. Below is some related code.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="videos">
    <div>
      <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
      <canvas id="localCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
      <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
      <canvas id="remoteCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 320px;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: false,
  video: true
})
.then(gotStream)
.catch(function(e) {
  alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
});

function gotStream(stream) {    
  console.log('Adding local stream.');
  localStream = stream;
  localVideo.srcObject = stream;

  sendMessage('got user media');
  if (isInitiator) {
    maybeStart();
  }
}
```

**Once we get the stream from camera, We are creating peer Connection and we are adding the local video stream and canvas stream (localCanvas.captureStream) to the connection in the below function. Not sure whether we can add 2 streams to a peer connection.**

```
function maybeStart() {
    createPeerConnection();
    const canvas_stream = localCanvas.captureStream(25);
    pc.addStream(localStream);      // IS THIS CORRECT? ADDING 2 STREAMS on a connection
    pc.addStream(canvas_stream);    // IS THIS CORRECT? ADDING 2 STREAMS on a connection
}

function createPeerConnection() {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
}
```

**Below function is being called twice. So I think adding 2 streams to the peer connection should be working. But not sure which one is real video stream and which one is canvas stream. So first time when we enter the function, we are attaching the stream to remote video object (as we added the video stream first and canvas stream next to the peer connection). But not sure how to use the canvas stream to display on the remote video as we can't use the canvas with media stream.**

```
function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  if(videoStream == false) {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
  }
  else {
      // HOW TO OVERLAY THE CANVAS HERE WITH THE CANVAS STREAM?
      videoStream = true;
  }
}
```

We are facing below issues.

- We need to pass local video stream and canvas stream (for the
  drawings on the video). So we are using addstream() to the peer
  connection two times. Is this correct? Can we do it this way?
- If we can add 2 streams like above, how can we distinguish whether it
  is video stream or canvas stream at the remote client?
- Somehow even if we distinguish and add the video stream to video tag
  source, how can I use canvas stream to overlay the canvas drawings on
  the video as canvas won't work with media stream?

Can any one please let me know how to fix these issues?

Comment: If the canvas stream is just for drawing event, why not send the drawing event, event details on data channels as messages, and draw on canvas based on received messages.

Comment: Alternative solution could be drawing a video onto canvas (using `context.drawImage(video, ...)`, then applying the drawing on top of it and sending a single canvas stream to the other side, if it meets your requirements.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: If I do that, I am not sure how the audio can be synchronized with Video as we are painting video as bunch of images.

Comment: @Colin, that will be huge data. For example, if I draw a big curve, I need to send all the coordinates involved in the curve. If I send the first and last points, it will be straight line.

Comment: @kadina I think message size smaller 16kiB won't be a problem. Even if you draw a big curve. And on canvas, you can draw curve by using arc, quadraticCurveTo, bezierCurveTo functions, you don't need to send all coordinates on curve.

Comment: @Colin: Thanks a lot for the useful information. I used data channel and I am able to replicate the drawings. Can you please post your comments as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @kadina doesn't matter, I'm happy to help.